# Unable to call a method when HW menu button is clicked

Tags: android, andengine

I just started to develop a game with andEngine and now having trouble with the hardware Menu button in android device. What I want to do is to call a method "`showMenu()`" to show a custom menu scene that I made with the following code below. However, whenever I tap the HW menu button, the list of apps shows up instead of the method. How can I manage to call a method via menu button ? I would love to hear from you !

```
 @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            //if paused
            if (isPaused) {
                //use thread when tring to use detachself and detachChildren
                getBaseActivity().runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < pauseBg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                            unregisterTouchArea((ButtonSprite) pauseBg.getChildByIndex(i));
                        }
                        pauseBg.detachChildren();
                        pauseBg.detachSelf();
                    }
                });
                isPaused = false;
                isTouchEnabled = true;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } else if (e.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            //if not paused show menu
            if (!isPaused) {
                showMenu();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind a lot of android devices don't come with a physical or touch screen menu button. The button on your device is most likely the task manager button, whose purpose is meant to do exactly as you described (show a list of running/background apps).

It is best practice to avoid overriding the menu button in games, or at the very least you should provide the client with an alternative on-screen sprite to act as a menu button.